# ¿Cómo separar un registro VARCHAR2 de comas en PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, bucles, plsql, oracle-11g, cursor

Tengo un registro de alimentos:

```
pollo, carne, pez, res, zanahoria
```

Lo que quisiera es con un cursor ir separando cada alimento e ingresar cada uno en un registro nuevo

```
pollo
carne
pez
res
zanahoria
```

Estoy usando Oracle 11g - tablas temporales - PL/SQL y esta es mas o menos la idea:

```
CURSOR MIC IS 
        SELECT UPPER(ALIMENTOS) FROM COMIDAS

BEGIN
FOR I IN MIC LOOP
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existen múltiples formas de hacerlo. Una relativamente sencilla es usar `CONNECT BY` y `REGEXP_SUBSTR()`. `CONNECT BY` permite ir recorriendo recursivamente la cadena, mientras que  `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` extrae los elementos de la misma.

```
WITH rws AS (
  SELECT alimentos FROM Comidas
)
  SELECT LTRIM( regexp_substr (
           alimentos,
           '[^,]+',
           1,
           level
         )) value
  FROM rws
  CONNECT BY level <= 
    LENGTH( alimentos) - LENGTH( REPLACE( alimentos, ',' ) ) + 1;
```